# Why I am getting this error An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have done this many times and no error occurred ever but this time it's annoying.

Error:

**An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.**

```
Select aw.AppliedWorkID, aw.AppliedDateTime, aw.NIT_No, aw.Work_No, c.Name, c.CNIC, c.FatherName, w.WorkName, ISNULL(Withdrawn,0) as Withdrawn from AppliedWorks aw
Inner Join Contractors c
ON c.ContractorID= aw.Contractor_ID
Inner Join Works w
ON w.NIT_No= aw.NIT_No and w.WorkNo= aw.Work_No
Where ISNULL(aw.Withdrawn,0)= 1 and aw.NIT_No= @NITNO and aw.Work_No= @WorkNo
AND (datetime, w.OpeningDate, 106) +' '+ Convert(varchar(7), w.OpeningTime)) <= Convert(datetime, Getdate())
```

Comment: Side note: There's no need to `Convert(datetime, Getdate())` - `getdate()` already returns a datetime. And you might want to consider changing your table structure to store `Opening` in a single `datetime` column rather than split date/time columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think CONVERT was missing in last line

Change from

```
AND (datetime, w.OpeningDate, 106) +' '+ Convert(varchar(7), w.OpeningTime)) 
<= Convert(datetime, Getdate())
```

To

```
AND Convert(datetime, w.OpeningDate, 106) +' '+ Convert(varchar(7), w.OpeningTime)) 
<= Convert(datetime, Getdate())
```

Comment: @Covert: if thats it - maybe you should mark your question as answerd :-)